# Are there any issues when choosing \t as a delimiter inside keys in Redis?

Tags: redis

I'm looking into delimiters for namespaces in Redis keys. Because the article numbers and stuff I'm going to use as parts of the keys have a lot of chars like `:`, `-`, `_` and so on. I was thinking to use a tabulator `\t`. Are there any known issues with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to use whatever characters you want inside redis keys, redis is binary safe.
We even use null characters inside keys in some specific situations. From a binary client (so not a command line tool like redis-cli) even null characters are fine.

This is described in the redis.io [datatypes](http://redis.io/topics/data-types). A redis string is binary safe, and more advanced redis datatypes use redis strings.

*A note on null characters inside keys:*

A real-world scenario is the use of UUID byte sequences (instead of its ascii GUID representation) as keys. You would choose this for minimizing memory usage. Another is when using the MsgPack serialization format (natively supported in redis Lua scripting), which is binary, and certainly contains null characters now and then. The downside of using null characters is, ofcourse, readability when debugging or logging, the ability to do easy command-line piping, and/or usage of the interactive redis-cli client.

Hope this helps, TW

Comment: It helps. Thanks. What are situations where you would use a null character? A link to the documentation would be great.

Comment: I am also unsure with the `\t` because it could end up literally. We are using Perl as our primary language, and doing `$redis->get('foo\tbar')` would be literal backlash and T while `"foo\tbar"` would interpolate the tab. That seems prone to mistakes.

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer with a link to the documentation, and some more info on null characters.

Comment: About your question on escape characters in Perl: that goes for any programming language. You have to know how the compiler/interpreter of the language treats string literals. If this scares you, or is not suited for your company (which is a valid question btw), you shouldn't use \t, and probably forbid all whitespace characters except space. Keep in mind that newline characters are even more error prone, since the defaults are different on different operating systems (windows: \r\n, unix \r, mac past: \n present: \r).